# Picture Module, Amazon S3, CloudFront CDN setup?

Tags: 7, media, cdn

Has any of you successfully set up the Picture Module for responsive images to work with Amazon S3 and CloudFront CDN?

I have been successful setting Drupal up to work with Amazon S3 and CloudFront, but the moment I enable the Picture module, things stop working.

All images that were uploaded previous to activating the Picture Module are coming from CloudFront, but new images that I upload are being pulled from the default Drupal file system.

I have configured the image fields to upload to upload to Amazon S3.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!